# Pass viewdata to a create form MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewdata

I passed the id from one controller (Index)  to another (Details), and added a ViewData statement to save data in the details view, and forward it to a View on another controller.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonID)
```

How do I modify this statement to enter a ViewData element?

Comment: Could you put your controller code please?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Strongly typed helper such as EditorFor work only with strong types. ViewBag is weak typing. So don't use ViewBag. Use a view model instead.